# those of you who

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

a. You, who live here, will eventually have to leave.

b. You who live here will eventually have to leave.

Are both of the above acceptable?

Is there any difference in their meanings?

Could (b) be used instead of (c)?

c. Those of you who live here will have to leave.

Answer (score 2):

The commas in the first one suggest a "non restrictive" relationship between "you" and the relative clause "who live here".

So in the first one, everyone who is being addressed as "you" lives here and everyone will have to leave.

In the second there is a restrictive relationship.  Some of the people addressed as "you" live here, and that subset will have to leave.

The same restrictive relationship is implied by (c). And (c) could be used as an alternative.